# How to use the new iOS 6 registerClass UITableView method with multiple cell types

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am running into an issue using the new registerClass method for UITableView. I register my cell fine, and then when I want to make a cell I do this:

```
static NSString *imageIdentifier = @"image";
CustomCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:imageIdentifier];

if (!cell) {
    cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithQuestion:self.question reuseIdentifier:imageIdentifier];
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
}
```

This may not be the modern way to do it, but it is how I've done it before. The issue is that because the new registerClass method makes a new cell **for** you if there isn't one in the queue, the if (!aCell) check fails, and the cell isn't built correctly.

Am I not using this new approach to dequeueing correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Set up the cell (in your case the selectionStyle) in the `prepareForReuse` method of your UITableViewCell subclass.

2) Set the content of the cell after the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` call in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method.

`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` will always return a cell if you have called `registerClass:` with the corresponding identifier.

Answer (score 1):

You use the new method, `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`, and leave out the if clause.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    // configure cell here
    return cell;
}
```

You would use the same reuse identifier when you register your class or xib.

Comment: Only works if your tableview is connected to Nib or Storyboard.